# If an even function $f(x)$ has a local maximum value at $x=c$, can anything be said about the value of $f$ at $x=-c$? Give reasons for your answer.

Tags: functions, derivatives

By simply using the definition of an even function I can say that there must exist a point $(-c,f(c))$ on the graph of $f$. And since $f(c)$ is a local maximum, then a local maximum value exists at $x=-c$.

Is this explanation sufficient? I'm not sure how to "show" or prove this using only the definition of a local maximum given in the textbook I am using which says,

"$f$ has a local maximum at an interior point $x=c$ if $f(x)\le f(c)$ for all $x$ in some open interval $(c-\delta,c+\delta),\delta>0$."

Comment: Should be a local maximum

Answer (score 3):

**Using your definition:** Let $f(x)\leq f(c)$ for all $x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$, for $\delta>0$.

Now consider $-x\in(-c-\delta,-c+\delta)$. Since $f$ is even, we know that $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $f(-c)=f(c)$, hence:

$$f(-x)=f(x)\leq f(c)=f(-c).$$

This means that $x=-c$ is a point where $f$ achieves a local maximum.